# Get IndexPath Value in UICollectionViewCell Class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have a UiCollectionViewCell Class as follow:

```
class DateCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let dateLabel = UILabel()
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()        

        dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))
        dateLabel.textAlignment = .Left
        dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13)

        dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)

    }
}
```

I want to change the Y-positon of my first row first column cell label only, rest of the cells label remain unchanged.So for this I need IndexPath value so I can check for section and row of current cell.

How can I get this ??
Is there any other way to do what I want to get ???

Comment: Depend on where you need to retrieve the indexPath. If you have the cell you can get it like this: let index_path=collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell).

Comment: Your collection view datasource knows which cell it is setting up, so it should set a property on the cell that tells it how to render. It isn't the cells job to know which indexPath it is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell : DateCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell 

   if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0  {
        // do your custom changes for the cell
    }

   return cell // your default cell
}
```